# Unescape attribute the_title() on CDATA in RSS feed

Tags: functions

My goal is to **unescape the string**.

So, how would I do it in Wordpress? Let's say I have the whole string below:

```
He said, &#8220;This is how it works...&#8221;
```

I can't seem to find a built-in Wordpress function to unescape `&#8220;` and `&#8221;`. This is if using unescape on `the_title()` (sorry for not specifying earlier).

On the rss feed items, I have this code where `the_title()` should be unescaped:

```
<item>
  <title><![CDATA[<?php the_title(); ?>]]></title>
  <link><?php echo get_permalink(); ?></link>
  <date><?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></date>
</item>
```

Comment: check this link hope this will help you http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is one. Escaping is harder than unescaping (you have decide what exactly to escape and where).

Just use PHP `html_entity_decode` function.

Comment: You are actually right that this works. I guess I stated the wrong question. I actually tried `stripslashes`, `stripcslashes`, and `html_entity_decode` on `the_title()`. But it does not work this way. +1 for help.

Comment: And why are these chars escaped in the_title()? What exactly are you doing?

Comment: I was using `<![CDATA[<?php the_title(); ?>]]>` inside the items of RSS feed.

Comment: OK, but `the_title()` should not escape anything by itself, AFAIR...